# django-registration activation_email.txt

Tags: django, django-registration

how does it write.

code example please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `activation_email.txt` is a django template which contains whatever you want, plus a link back to your site.

Something like:

> To activate your account, go here: 
>           {{ site }}/accounts/activate/{{ activation_key }}/

Take a look at the quick start in the docs folder (or read online [here](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/docs/quickstart.rst).)

[This site](http://www.undercostruction.eu/2007/11/02/templates-for-django-registration/) *had* an implementation walkthrough, but the link is dead now.

Comment: [This site](http://www.undercostruction.eu/2007/11/02/templates-for-django-registration/) is a dead link

Comment: This is better, as it uses the protocol (in this case http) and checks the URLconf for the correct URL: http://{{ site }}{% url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}